# Is there a way or built in method to get the text from android material TextInputLayout(om.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout)?

Tags: android, material-design

I have tried using getText() but this isnt available when using that Textfield and below is the textfield:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstnametxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:hint="First Name">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Pixyboy, it seems you have posted this to the wrong stack exchange site. You might be looking for [SO] or [Android.SE]. I have migrated your question there as it is off-topic here.

Comment: I added tags (was untagged before due to migration). Hope the tags make sense, otherwise fell free to retag.

Answer (score 0):

`TextInputLayout` has a `editText` field, you can cast it to your `TextInputEditText` and get the text inside it using it's `text` field. For example in Kotlin it would look like

```
val editText = textInputLayout.editText as TextInputEditText
editText.text
```